# Microstrip circuit Simulation

Tags: ads

How can I simulate the below circuit to show its transmission coefficient?

[image]

I have developed the circuit as in the diagram but what is missing to view the transmission coefficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ADS, you'll need to either

- Get rid of the Port objects and connect a signal source and termination to the two ends of the trace. In recent versions of ADS, there is one `Term` object type that is used for both the stimulus and termination in S-parameter simulations.

or

- Make a higher level schematic with a signal source and termination, that connects to an instantiation of this subcircuit as a 2-port.

Then

- Add a simulation object to the schematic. You probably want an `S_Param` simulation object.
- Click the "Simulate" button.
- Graph the `S(2,1)` output data to get the transmission coefficient.

Comment: I have added a termination in place of the ports without adding any signal source and it has worked fine , so is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, in an S-parameter simulation, the termination (if you use a `Term` object instead of just a resistor) is both a termination and a signal source.

Comment: Thank you very much